# A pretty variable in URL (PHP + Apache)

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I have asked the same question yesterday, but was downvoted. Struggling for a whole day to find an answer in related answers and documentations but without any luck.

I repeat the question again, maybe this time I can communicate it more clearly.

I have a single page app at **site.com**

Need to let users create any variables to pass to front end using the url. A variable should be visible in url even though such page does not exist, e.g. **site.com/variable** (the format of the url should be exactly as shown here).

For the backend I am using PHP and Apache.

My htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: have you looked up how to use .htaccess to render a single page no matter the url, without modifying the url itself? This sounds like it might be a solution for you

Comment: yes, it should be something like this, but does not work: RewriteRule /(.*) /$1

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [URL rewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). It is a well known feature allowing to rewrite a template URL to a specific URL. The most common use case is to move the components of the URL to GET parameters.

I'm not really used to Apache, but a .htaccess file like this should do the job

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?variable=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So everything that is next to the root, should be transfered to the index.php, filling the $_GET['variable'] with all the content. The operation takes place on apache side, so there is no visible URL change for the client.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only manage to get this error:
Not Found
The requested URL /variable was not found on this server.

Comment: @KPzzle, maybe add your full .htaccess file to the original question, you may be missing something like `RewriteEngine on` etc, that would be one reason for the not found error.

Comment: I am using only these two lines, either like @Jordan Quagliatini wrote or like this: 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /^(.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: did you check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled ?

Comment: Can you try with the Rewrite Rule I gave you as example, moving to a querystring seems the solution to me

Comment: Yep, this looks a right solution, but I get 500 error: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: looks like this is the right direction, still no luck but will explore it further...

Answer (score 0):

```
index.php
<a href="1">click</a>

submit.php
<?php 
echo $_GET['id'];
 ?>

.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  submit.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please provide more detail in your answers. Explain how this would help.